# UIImageView Autolayout on PushingViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview, autolayout

I'm using adaptive layout and in some ViewControllers I've added an UIImageView as background, and then over it an UIView with some opacity in background color to show the background.

The problem is that when I push to that ViewController, the UIImageView doesn't follow correctly the animation of push, but it appears immediately on pressing the UIButton and then it appears the UIView Over.

I've already done a trick that on DidAppear the UIImageView fades in, but it's not right.

What I'm getting wrong?

Comment: Could you include the code which is doing this? It might be easier to see where you're going wrong that way.

Comment: There's not any code, it's only storyboard and auto layout. The only thing that I can say is that both UIImageView and over UIView are pinned to container view, so that they cover the whole screen.